# C++ template value in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, typename

I want to implement a class containing a dictionary among other things. There's a simplified example, where I use a map to achieve it:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Position {
public:
    typedef std::string AttrKey;
    typedef std::string AttrValue;
    typedef std::map<AttrKey, AttrValue> AttrMap;

    Position() = default;

    void set(const AttrKey& key, const AttrValue& value)
    {
        attrs[key] = value;
    }

    AttrValue get(const AttrKey& key) const
    {
        const auto found = attrs.find(key);
        if (found != attrs.end())
            return found->second;
        return "";
    }

    const AttrMap& getAttrs() const
    {
        return attrs;
    }

private:
    AttrMap attrs;

};

int main()
{
    Position p;
    p.set("some_key", "some_value");
    std::cout << "This is the value: "<< p.get("some_key");
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'd like to dynamically decide on the value type so that the dictionary would contain not only string values. I'm a pythonist, so I have little understanding of what I do. But I nicetry to make a `Foo` template class so that any value would fit in and alias it as an `AttrValue` (**and I also don't want to use Boost**):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef T Bar;
};


class Position {
public:
    template <typename T>
    using Bar = typename Foo<T>::Bar;

    typedef std::string AttrKey;
    typedef Bar AttrValue;
    typedef std::map<AttrKey, AttrValue> AttrMap;

    Position() = default;

    void set(const AttrKey& key, const AttrValue& value)
    {
        attrs[key] = value;
    }

    AttrValue get(const AttrKey& key) const
    {
        const auto found = attrs.find(key);
        if (found != attrs.end())
            return found->second;
        return "";
    }

    const AttrMap& getAttrs() const
    {
        return attrs;
    }

private:
    AttrMap attrs;

};

int main()
{
    Position p;
    p.set("some_key", 42);
    std::cout << "This is the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything: "<< p.get("some_key");
    return 0;
}
```

Here I get an error `invalid use of template-name ‘Position::Bar’ without an argument list`.

Comment: If you're a Pythonist, then a good starting point would be to think about how you would implement Python (values) in C++.

Comment: `Bar` is not a type - it's an infinite family of types. It's also rather pointless - for any `T`, `Bar<T>` or `Foo<T>::Bar` is just an elaborate way to write `T`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, there's duck typing in Python, such problem is impossible due to the language itself.

Comment: @Dankevich: Yes, but how would you *implement* that -- say, how would you write a Python interpreter in C++? The answer will contain the essential solution to your question.

Comment: Have a look at std::any